# Which of this usage is correct 'have not been understood' or 'have not been understanding'?

Tags: tense, present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

1. They have not been understood the problem till now.
2. They have not been understanding the problem till now.

Which of this is correct?

I think I can't use 'understanding' because 'to understand' can't be in process. But if I go by the present perfect continuous form understanding is the correct usage.

Comment: Normally "They have not understood the problem until now".

Comment: (1) is grammatically incorrect. (2) is not idiomatic because we don't use _understand_ in the continuous tense. Peter's version is the correct one.

Comment: Understand is a **stative verb** and so it is not normally used in continuous tenses in British or American Engish. Stative verbs are used in continuous tenses in Indian English. Here's the British take on stative verbs: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/stative-verbs

Comment: if the examples were supposed to be in the **passive voice** then it's "*THE PROBLEM **has not been understood** [by them] until now*”